# monodevelop csproj load failed: version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to load a Microsoft Visual Studio project made in Windows on a Ubuntu 15.10 Linux machine. I'm setup with Mono v. 4.2.2 and Monodevelop 5.10.

The project includes a .sln in its root, which wouldn't load in the beginning. But after removing VisualStudioVersion and 
MinimumVisualStudioVersion (as given here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15171/error-loading-project-version-string-portion-was-too-short-or-too-long) it loads fine. However, now a similar error comes up, but on the .csproj file, when the project loads: "Load failed: Version string portion was too short or too long".

The error give me short to nothing, as I've got no idea where in the file it fails to load.

I've changed Project ToolsVersion from "12.0" to "4.0" (as given here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10460/any-workaround-for-this-error-unknown-toolsversion-12-0), but that didn't solve it.

**EDIT**

I've tried to change `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to:
`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`, but it still doesn't work.

I'm rather new to ASP.NET, so any tips on getting project version number and files required for you guys to see are appreciated :)

Thanks in advance -

Comment: Have you tried to change target framework from `v4.5.1` or `v4.5.2` to `v4.5`?

Comment: Hi @LexLi - thanks for replying :) I've just changed it to:   `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`  
But it still doesn't work. v4.5 should work partially on Mono according to: mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility  
Could it be: `<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion> <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</V‌​SToolsPath>`

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a new project in Monodevelop and hereafter adding references and content to it - manually copy-and-pasting - worked way better even though a bit tedious..